# HttpModule not fired when hitting WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webmethod, httpmodule

I am using an asp.net HttpModule to perform a security test on my web application. The problem I am having is on some pages I am using jquery ajax with WebMethods. The WebMethods appear not to be triggering the module. Is there anyway that this can be achieved?

My code is as so:

```
public class MyModule: IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += (new EventHandler(this.Application_Test));
    }

    private void Application_Test(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

WebMethod that is called:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static void SearchMachines(String searchString)
{}
```

Comment: Did you configure your HttpModule in the web.config of your webservice?

Comment: I too am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using webmetod in your aspx page.

Webmethods are static and HttpModules will only get triggered when a request is passed with instance of a webpage(page class).